# If Facebook says I've logged on from an unknown location, does that mean someone knows my password?

Tags: facebook, privacy, security

The email I received pointed me to a screen similar to this one:

http://www.securitygeneration.com/security/facebooks-suspicious-login-tracking/

The location was most definitely nowhere near me, so I'm pretty sure I wasn't the cause of it.

[image: Facebook login image]

Comment: I suppose, since FB didn't ask me to change my password, that it's not an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Not...necessarily.

Do you have any apps connected to your Facebook account? For instance, I use IFTTT to pull some information from my account. The logins by IFTTT will be from wherever their servers are located. Sometimes my wireless carrier will show me hundreds of miles from where I really am and the IP address my phone has when I check Facebook will reflect that. Then there's the added security measure of using a proxy to log in. That will show as being where the proxy server is, not where you are.

Geolocating based on IP address is inexact at best.

That said, it wouldn't be a bad idea to change your password. The worst that happens is that those connected apps may start failing and you'll need to reconnect.

It would also be a good idea to review the [devices that have access to your account](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security&section=devices&view) as well as [your active sessions](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security&section=sessions&view). If anything looks hinkey there be sure to disconnect it *and* change your password. Review the other [security settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security) and consider tightening them up.

If that's an actual screen grab you've posted, though, that definitely looks bad. A login halfway 'round the world using a completely different OS? I'd jump on that right away.

Comment: I should find the actual message. I'm not sure it used the word "login", and might instead have used the word "access". Problem is, it's hard to find that message again once you've dismissed it!

Comment: The "active sessions" should be helpful.

Comment: It showed nothing out of the ordinary, and I had already identified the previous access as suspicious, so I imagine any previous users may have already been kicked.